# How to Send push notifications using One Signal + PHP + Server API?

Tags: php, android, api, server, onesignal

I am using one signal to send push notification for android app. My question is

How Can I setup send push notifications using server rest api?

Comment: There is a PHP example on their website: https://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/notifications-create-notification. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: offcourse, as per document i done but it shows error like this

Comment: JSON sent: {"app_id":"eec33e8e-5774-4b74-9aae-37370778c4b2","included_segments":["All"],"send_after":"Fri May 02 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)","data":{"foo":"bar"},"isAndroid":true,"contents":{"en":"English Message"}} JSON received: {"allresponses":"{\"id\":\"\",\"recipients\":0,\"errors\":[\"All included players are not subscribed\"],\"warnings\":[\"You must configure Android notifications in your OneSignal settings if you wish to send messages to Android players.\"]}"}

Comment: The new link is: https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
<?PHP
function sendMessage(){
    $content = array(
        "en" => 'Testing Message'
        );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        'included_segments' => array('All'),
        'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        'large_icon' =>"ic_launcher_round.png",
        'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
print("\nJSON sent:\n");
print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

$response = sendMessage();
$return["allresponses"] = $response;
$return = json_encode( $return);
print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
print($return);
print("\n");
?>
```

Comment: Hello Kishan...could you please help me with something? how do you get that 'data' => array("foo" => "bar") ? is it in the app.js? where? what do i have to do? regards

Comment: @Japa sorry for my late replay . i can help just tell me where you didn't understand.

Comment: Hi Kishan...thank you for answering, i´ve got it, i now understand, thanks anyway

Comment: how do you setup the title on the notification as "contents" is the body message?

Comment: @Alberto yes and you can checkout documentation of onesignal.

Answer (score 4):

You can always refer to the official docs:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-example-code-create-notification

- 'app_id' is currently known as (OneSignal App ID) in the OneSignal
  Settings->Keys and IDs
- in 'Authorization: Basic xxx...' past the "REST API Key" just below the App ID

Comment: Documentation include code examples for many languages. For example
"Send based on filters/tags - Create notification"
Shell, JSON, PHP, C# (.NET standard), C# (ASP.NET), Ruby (Rails), Python, NodeJS, Perl, Parse Cloud, GameSparks, Java

Answer (score 2):

I see you have set isAndroid=true, but OneSignal is returning an error that shows that the application with ID `eec33e8e-5774-4b74-9aae-37370778c4b2` does not have Android notifications enabled.

Make sure your app ID is correct, and if it is, that Android notifications are enabled in your OneSignal settings.

Comment: how do you setup the title on the notification as "contents" is the body message?

Answer (score 2):

$to - Device ID

$title - Notification Title

$message - Notification Message

$img - Full image link

Usage:

### sendnotification($to, $title, $message, $img);

With Demo Values :

### sendnotification("Device_ID","Test Notification","Test Message","https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png");

```
function sendnotification($to, $title, $message, $img)
{
    $msg = $message;
    $content = array(
        "en" => $msg
    );
    $headings = array(
        "en" => $title
    );
    if ($img == '') {
        $fields = array(
            'app_id' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
            "headings" => $headings,
            'include_player_ids' => array($to),
            'large_icon' => "https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png",
            'content_available' => true,
            'contents' => $content
        );
    } else {
        $ios_img = array(
            "id1" => $img
        );
        $fields = array(
            'app_id' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
            "headings" => $headings,
            'include_player_ids' => array($to),
            'contents' => $content,
            "big_picture" => $img,
            'large_icon' => "https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png",
            'content_available' => true,
            "ios_attachments" => $ios_img
        );

    }
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=**APP_KEY**',
        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```