# Push notifications on IONIC 2 using PHP server side

Tags: php, android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am doing an app with ionic 2 angular 2 and Typescript and i need to implement push notifications into it. I already used local notifications and i used the ionic 2 Dashboard to send a notification to all app users. But i didn't find really how can i make it automated.

I want to make the server do some checkups on the database to see if there are entries that are relativly new and if so it automatically pushes the new notification to all devices.

Any help on how to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explore OneSignal Push Notification Service. Ionic native also have 
[OneSignal plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/).

Ionic part - [OneSignal plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/)'s documentation.

For PHP part - check [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767429/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-one-signal-php-server-api).