# One Signal Web Push Notification Custom Message PHP

Tags: php, web, push-notification

I am looking for a way to send custom push notification. I have already have a One Signal account and it works on my website. Now, I need to send push notification when someone creates a message to users. I have email notifications which work. How can I create custom push notification through php?

Thanks

Comment: what exactly you mean by custom ? I think One Signal have all things we need to send for push notification , use tags or filter to send push notification to specific user

Comment: I mean custom notification for messages. For example for push notification which includes username and message. So when a user receives a message on the site, it will be sent as a push notification. I am trying to do this in php.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767429/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-one-signal-php-server-api